can't retrieve image id from build stream when trying to debug with a remote interpreter defined with docker
I get "java.util.concurrent.completionexception: com.intellij.docker.agent.apitaskexception: can't retrieve image id from build stream" when trying to debug a certain python script with a remote python interpreter defined either using a docker or docker-compose.
I can run the image and can launch my app using docker-compose up from terminal without issues. Docker is well defined within pycharm as I see it in the services.
pycharm profession 2024.3.1
Windows environment with docker 4.20.1 with wsl
My computer isn't connected to the internet.
I read previous similar topics but they all mentioned the obvious things of verifying the docker image and docker plugin to pycharm.
what I'm missing?
